# lines seen on screens near layouts in Android 7 Nougat

Tags: android, line, android-linearlayout, android-7.0-nougat, android-layout-weight

No issues below Android 7, but on Android 7 there are lines every where on my screens. Specifically where I have used LinearLayouts and weights.

I have tested with two motorola devices with Android 7, those are 1- Moto G4 Plus and 2- Moto Z

[image]

I have marked 4 such lines in screenshot.

**Do anyone have solved the issue?**

**For some reasons, i can't share my code here**

Comment: Then create *different* code that demonstrates the problem, and provide a [mcve] out of that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I had added the line `<item name="android:divider">@color/black</item>` line in my app theme present in styles.xml to show divider between tabs.

Removing that line solved the problem.

But don't know why only those two devices(1- Moto G4 Plus and 2- Moto Z) were showing that problem. May be it was visible because of Full HD resolution of those mobiles.. don't know...